# no '-setBorderColor:' method found on UIView layer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation

I have the following code in two different classes (both subclasses of UIView). In one place it works fine, the border is drawn. In the other place I get warnings about methods not being found, and of course the border doesn't get drawn. How is this possible?

```
UIView* test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,100)];
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[test.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]]; //no '-setBorderColor:' method found 
[test.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];  //no '-setBorderWidth:' method found 

[self addSubview:test];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your file. That's where all of the CoreAnimation classes are defined.